# Java treeSet in a map

Tags: java

Java newbie, what I am trying to do is retrieve a string name that prints to the screen if one of the multiple values is within a range as follows:

```
public class SuperHeroes {
private Map<String, Set<Integer>> names;
private Set<Integer> pageNum;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class SuperHeroes
     */
    public SuperHeroes() {
        names = new HashMap<>();
        pageNum = new TreeSet<>();
    }

    /**
     * The fill() method creates 2 entries.
     */
    public void fill() {
        pageNum.add(1);
        pageNum.add(3);
        pageNum.add(7);
        names.put("Kent,Clark", pageNum);

        pageNum = new TreeSet<>();
        pageNum.add(2);
        pageNum.add(6);
        pageNum.add(4);
        names.put("Wayne,Bruce", pageNum);
    }

    public void findInRange(int num, int numb) {
        for (String eachName: names.keySet()) {
            for (int eachNum:pageNum) {
                if(eachNum >= num && eachNum <= numb) {
                    System.out.println(names.get(eachName));
                }
            }      
        }
    }
}
```

The result printed to screen would be the name of superhero if the pageNum is within the range. thr output I get at the moment is all the numbers. Any help would be gratefully received. If you can point me in the right direction would be a help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please consider using consistent indentation and dropping most of that vertical whitespace. I'm not entirely sure what the question is--please include details regarding how you're calling `findInRange`.

Comment: apologies for the indentation, haven't got to grips with copying and pasting into this site.

Comment: I have just tried to tidy the code up, to make it ledgable. Thanks

Comment: Calling the findInRange method from a test program at the moment and just parsing the 2 int numbers in.

Comment: Right. The point is *what* numbers are you passing in. In other words, allow people to recreate what you're doing.

Comment: The numbers will be user defined, what I then want is to check if any of the numbers within the treeset are within the range of what the user has inputed. Then based on this it will display the keyset. You will have to excuse me and my understanding of these types of forums, this is my first post. I have scoured the java docs and the internet.If you could point me in the right direction I would like to solve it myself. Thanks for you time and patience.

Comment: ... My point was that in order to get the same output you are, we need to provide the input you are using to generate the wrong results. Don's answer is likely what you're looking for--but by providing detailed information up-front you allow us to just run it and look at the output. It's often easier to do that than to try to figure things out just by looking.

Comment: If you post a concrete example of how you're calling this, what output you expect from the call and what output you're actually getting, we will be much more able to help diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody is interested I solved this with the following code:

```
public void findInRange(int num, int numb)
{
 for(String eachName: names.keySet())
 {
   pageNum = names.get(eachName);
   for (int eachNum:pageNum)
   {
    if(eachNum>=num&&eachNum<=numb||eachNum>=numb&&eachNum<=num)
    {
        System.out.println(eachName);
        break;
    }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou to all that commented and contributed it did help.

Answer (score 1):

First mistake in your code is the way you defined names and pageNum. It should be in this way:

```
public SuperHeroes() 
{
    names = new HashMap<String, Set<Integer>>();
    pageNum = new TreeSet<Integer>();
}
```

Now You could use `subSet()` method of `Treeset` to achieve what you looking for . Here the code goes:
**EDIT**: 
While retrieving the `Treeset` for given name from `names` the returned value is needed to be typecast to `TreeSet` type. Same is to be done while using the `subset` method with `tSet` .

```
   public void findInRange(int num, int numb) 
    {
        for (String eachName: names.keySet()) 
        {
            TreeSet<Integer> tSet = (TreeSet<Integer>)names.get(eachName);
            TreeSet<Integer> subSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
            subSet = (TreeSet<Integer>)tSet.subSet(num,true,numb,true);//for JDK 1.6 or above. returns num<=numbers<=numb
            //TreeSet<Integer> subSet = tSet.subSet(num-1, numb+1);//for JDK version less than 1.6
            if (subSet.size() != 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Hero is "+eachName);
                break;//you can ommit it if you want to print all heroes having pagenum in range num to numb
            }
        }      
    }
```

The `fill` method is also needed to be modified as:

```
public void fill() 
{
    pageNum.add(1);
    pageNum.add(3);
    pageNum.add(7);
    names.put("Kent,Clark", pageNum);

    pageNum = new TreeSet<Integer>();//Use proper way of object construction with generics
    pageNum.add(5);
    pageNum.add(6);
    pageNum.add(4);
    names.put("Wayne,Bruce", pageNum);
}
```

Comment: The syntax for his variables os perfectly fine as of Java 7.

Comment: This just gives incompatable types at the tSet as eachName is a String object, if I change the TreeSet to String type it also comes up with the same error...

Answer (score 0):

First, you must use the name of the super hero for obtaining the treeset, then read every item in the tree and compare it with the number you need, if the comparison is true print the name of the superhero.

Look at this link

http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/java-treeset-example/

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You're telling it to print the numbers corresponding to the found name with the line

```
                System.out.println(names.get(eachName));
```

If you only want to show the name, that should just be

```
                System.out.println(eachname);
```

Comment: I have tried each name and it prints out all the names provided the range is large enough, however when I close the range it prints nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Well we are all guessing here. Maybe you need this :

```
public void findInRange(int num, int numb)

    {

        for (String eachName : names.keySet())

        {
            for (int eachNum : pageNum)

            {

                if (eachNum >= num && eachNum <= numb)

                {
                    for (int temp = 0; temp < eachNum; temp ++)
                    {
                    System.out.println(eachName);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: with `for` statement added. But with the last edit I think I'm wrong. I thought he wants to print the name as many times as each number that's in range..

Comment: I only want the name of the superhero if one of the numbers from the treeset are within the range from what the user inputs.

Comment: Then you should go with `Don Roby's` answer. Just fix the `println` your code is doing just that - checking for numbers in range and printing the name i there's an actual hit. The only problem MAYBE is that if you have more than one number that's within the range you'll get the name prinlined as many times as are the hits you have.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering, you have initialised an pageNum in the constructor, why you are creating another one in the method `fill()`? That maybe the reason because the one in constructor may "hiding" from the second one in the fill method.